# In openCV warpPerspective, how do I transform the left image and stitch it to the image on the right?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching

I'm trying to do an image stitch using OpenCV by doing SIFT->KNN->warpPerspective. There are whole lot of resource on how to warp the image on the right to be stitched on to the destination on the left. I've tried calculating the homography matrix for warping left image to be stitched to the right and that seems to work. Problem is, I can't stitch the image together with cv2.warpPerspective since it seems to put the image in where it should be if the right side image is warped.

My code is basically:

```
result = cv2.warpPerspective(left, H, (left.shape[1] + right.shape[1], left.shape[0])
result[0:right.shape[0], result.shape[1]-right[1]:] = right
```

But this creates image offset shifted to the right. How could I stitch the images correctly?

Comment: Your problem as stated is not clear to me. Can you explain further and/or show a diagram or images.

Answer (score 1):

First you should resize the images and place them in a bigger image each with 
`outer_x= image_x*5` and `outer_y= image_y*3`

```
outer_x= image_x*5
outer_y= image_y*3
result = cv.warpPerspective(left_image, H, (outer_x, outer_y))
result[:, x_img * 2 : x_img*3] = right_image[j][:, x_img * 2 : x_img*3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears there are good number of resources to warp the image on the right to be stitched on to the destination on the left. However if we want to do the opposite of this i.e. transform the left image and stitch it to the image on the right, we can simply flip both the images then warp the image on the right to be stitched on to the destination on the left and then can flip the result back. This will be then equivalent to transform the left image and stitch it to the image on the right.